# laravel local.ERROR: Undefined index: HTTP_HOST in AppServiceProvider.php

Tags: php, laravel

i use laravel and have **multiple domain** like example.com , example.co , example.org

also i use **api** and laravel **task scaduleing** to update post view in day , week , month

using below code to make dl sever domain according user domain entered

**AppServiceProvider.php**

```
public function boot()
    {
        Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
        $dl_server = 'http://dl.' . str_replace('www.', '',$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) . '/';
        View::share('dl_server' , $dl_server);
    }
```

**but in laravel log file i got many error**

```
[2020-10-12 00:00:01] local.ERROR: Undefined index: HTTP_HOST {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Undefined index: HTTP_HOST at /home2/exampleco/domains/example.com/example/app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php:30)
[stacktrace]
#0 /home2/exampleco/domains/example.com/example/app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php(30): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\HandleExceptions->handleError(8, 'Undefined index...', '/home2/exampleco...', 30, Array)
#1 [internal function]: App\\Providers\\AppServiceProvider->boot()
#2 /home2/exampleco/domains/example.com/example/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(32): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#3 /home2/exampleco/domains/example.com/example/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php(522): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::Illuminate\\Container\\{closure}()
#4 /home2/exampleco/domains/example.com/example/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(90): value(Object(Closure))
#5 /home2/exampleco/domains/example.com/example/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(34): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Array, Object(Closure))
#6 /home2/exampleco/domains/example.com/example/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(591): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::call(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Array, Array, NULL)
#7 /home2/exampleco/domains/example.com/example/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(828): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->call(Array)
#8 /home2/exampleco/domains/example.com/example/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(811): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->bootProvider(Object(App\\Providers\\AppServiceProvider))
#9 [internal function]: Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->Illuminate\\Foundation\\{closure}(Object(App\\Providers\\AppServiceProvider), 23)
#10 /home2/exampleco/domains/example.com/example/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(812): array_walk(Array, Object(Closure))
#11 /home2/exampleco/domains/example.com/example/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/BootProviders.php(17): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->boot()
#12 /home2/exampleco/domains/example.com/example/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(211): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\BootProviders->bootstrap(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application))
#13 /home2/exampleco/domains/example.com/example/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(320): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->bootstrapWith(Array)
#14 /home2/exampleco/domains/example.com/example/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(129): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel->bootstrap()
#15 /home2/exampleco/domains/example.com/example/artisan(37): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#16 {main}
"}
```

and this error repeat every minute [2020-10-12 00:00:01] , [2020-10-12 00:01:01] , ...

**whats the problem ?**

Comment: it is not able to get `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` add check `isset()`

Comment: Probably some traffic that does not send the request with a `HTTP_HOST`, maybe someone that accesses your site by ip or other means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` only available if app called from HTTP Request, the error log say it's called from console (eg: task scheduling) so the variable is not exists.

Simply put variable checking using `empty()` or `isset()`, or check if not running in console with this sample code:

```php
if (!\App::runningInConsole()) {
    Log::debug("AppServiceProvider::boot ".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
}
```